# Add permission to a S3 object in AWS using Python and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, boto3

I was writing a code to add permission to an object in my bucket in S3. This will add a permission on the already present permission and then I want to perform a action on the file and then delete the created permission retaining the original permission.

I want to do this using boto3 library of python.

The code I have written so far is -

```
object_acl = s3.ObjectAcl(bucket_name,filename)
response = object_acl.put(AccessControlPolicy={
        'Grants': [
            {
                'Grantee': {
                    'DisplayName': 'DefaultPermisson',
                    'ID': '66414256532656',
                    'Type': 'CanonicalUser'
                  },
                'Permission': 'FULL_CONTROL'
            },
        ],

    })
print response
```

This is generating error and I am not able to create a new permission. Need help on this.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish? What is the "action" you wish to perform on the file? There is probably a better (and more secure) way to achieve your goal than temporarily changing permissions.

Comment: I am basically trying to give a temporary permission to download a file from S3 into a temp folder on a EC2 instance and then removing the permission. I will running a SQL append code inside the EC2 instance then.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Have you read [mcve] and [ask]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of granting temporary download access for a file, the most suitable solution would be to use an [Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

**By default, all objects in Amazon S3 are private.** You can then add permissions so that people can access your objects. This can be done via:

- **Access Control List** permissions on individual objects
- A **Bucket Policy** (that grants wide-ranging access based on path, IP address, referrer, etc)
- **IAM Users and Groups** (that grant permissions to Users with AWS credentials)
- **Pre-Signed URLs**

A **[Pre-Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)** can be used to grant access to S3 objects as a way of "overriding" access controls. A normally private object can be accessed via a URL by appending an expiry time and signature. This is a great way to serve private content without requiring a web server.

Rather than temporarily opening access to everyone, you can provide a URL that gives temporary access only to the people/applications you wish.

You say that your goal is *"to give a temporary permission to download a file from S3 into a temp folder on a EC2 instance"*. To achieve this, simply have your application generate the Pre-Signed URL, which can then be used to download the file. There is **no need to change the permissions** on the S3 object.

See:

- Boto documentation: [Generating Presigned URLs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls)
- The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 presign` documentation: [presign command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot John for the suggestion. I would definitely like to try this out.

Comment: great suggestion for an actual problem but not an answer to the factual question.